# Missing "Progress Report" option under Test Plans

Tags: azure-devops

cant seem to figure how to enable "Progress report" option under Test Plans. As per the documentation it should be there by default.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hg7wj.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Progress Report as a newly released feature may not have been deployed to your region. Newly released updates are deployed by region. There may be delayed deployment in your region. You can wait a while to see if this feature is visible. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: If this reply helps you ,could you [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.